# gridview not show default image when interner not available

Tags: android

im getting image url from database if internet available its automaticlaly display image but whrn nointernet available isnot show default image telll me why my question is when no internet available why not gridview load ic_launcher image on screen

```
      ExpandableHeightGridView gridview;
       CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
        static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();


       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(allergen);
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


        Category_ID.add((long) i);
        Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));  /image name
        Category_image.add(object.getString("image")); // image url

    }

                gridview= (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview) 
                        gridview.setAdapter(cla);




   public class CategoryListAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;


private AQuery androidAQuery;


public CategoryListAdapter3(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;

}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fifthscreen.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

 public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    androidAQuery = new AQuery(getcontext());
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem2, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    holder.txtText.setText(fifthscreen.Category_name.get(position));


  androidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).image(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position), true, true);

    return convertView;
}
private Activity getcontext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}

 }


  //viewitem2.xml//////

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  >

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:padding="5dp"

   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title2"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
android:paddingTop="10dp"


android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>



   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does this line do?   `androidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).image(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position), true, true);` And how do you set the image in adapter?

Comment: Aquery is android library to show image in gridview http://code.google.com/p/android-query/see this  i setimage in adapter at this line   gridview.setAdapter(cla);